# Android - When to use Shared Preferences and when to use SQLite

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite

I have created a food calories app, where users can enter foods and weights and my app will calculate the total calories. I have also created a 'Save' button, which when pressed will take the calories just calculated and display it on the Main Activity.

When the 'Save' button is pressed, I also want it to add any calories already on the Main Activity on, in order to get a Total Calories for all foods they have added throughout the day.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You must use a Database!

Comment: @Skynet Please don't shout at the OP!

Comment: I never did - It was an amicable advice! Please don't shout at me! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is save the total calories, the you don't even need an SQLite database, a simple [`SharedPreference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) will do. The official tutorial for how to get and set a `SharedPreference` is [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).